# converting datetime object with timezone to minutes

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

So I saved my datetime object with timezone, where it's GMT+8

```
2018-05-13 11:40:38.695000+08:00
```

What I want to do is convert this datetime object to minutes so I can compare it with something.

I tried doing this

```
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+%Z'
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-05-13 11:40:38.695000+08:00', fmt)
```

but it gives out the error of:

```
ValueError: time data '2018-05-13 11:40:38.695000+08:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+%Z'
```

Is there a more efficient way of implementing what I want to do? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your timezone from `+08:00` to `+0800` then use this:

```
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-05-13 11:40:38.695000+0800', fmt)
```

output: `datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 13, 11, 40, 38, 695000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 28800)))`